# Run multiple queries concurrently in SAS

Tags: sql, concurrency, sas

I have 36 completely independent queries I need to run on a regular bases which would go much faster if they could run 3 at a time (the database cancels our queries if we try and do more than 3 at a time) instead of each one waiting for the previous to finish.

I would like to do something like this

```
/* Some prep code here*/

/* Launch batch 1 containing queries 1-12*/
/* Immediately launch batch 2 (13-24) without waiting for 1-12 to finish*/
/* Immediately launch batch 3 (25-36)*/

/* Wait until all 3 batches are done and run some conclusion code*/
```

Or, if possible, just give it the 36 queries all together and have it run multiple at a time making sure to not have more than 3 running at any given time and any time one finishes, just add the next one from the stack.

Is this possible to do using SAS?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you have a SAS server and from your local machine you're launching the queries.
(If you dont and work locally its not a problem you can do a rsubmit to a spawner you have on your local machine)
Even with SAS/Base its possible to have 3 queries launch at the same time by having in a single code three connection.
I'm assuming here you dont want to share work libraries and are completely independent queries

```
option autosignon=yes;
option sascmd="!sascmd";

* some random data;
data prova1;
do i=1 to 20000000;
    x=rand('UNIFORM');
    output;
end;
run;

data prova2;
do i=1 to 20000000;
    y=rand('UNIFORM');
    output;
end;
run;
*open connection to the server ;

options comamid=tcp;
filename rlink "D:\SAS\SASFoundation\9.2\connect\saslink\tcpwin.scr";
%LET host1=nbsimbol59;
%LET host2=nbsimbol59;

signon remote=host1 script=rlink;
signon remote=host2 script=rlink;

rsubmit process=host1 wait=no inheritlib=(work=cwork);; 

   proc sort data=cwork.prova1 out=cwork.r1;
     by x;
   run;

   proc sort data=cwork.r1 out=cwork.r1a;
     by i;
   run;


endrsubmit;


rsubmit process=host2 wait=no inheritlib=(work=cwork);; 

   proc sort data=cwork.prova2 out=cwork.r2;
     by y;
   run;

   proc sort data=cwork.r2 out=cwork.r2a;
     by i;
   run;

endrsubmit;

/* Wait for both tasks to complete. */
waitfor _ALL_ host1 host2;

data r9;
     merge r1a (in=a) r2a (in=b);
    by i;
    if a and b;
    run;


signoff host1;
signoff host2;
```

Only problem with this sample code is that it will wait both task to end and atm it doesnt come to mind a way to have it launch another query as soon as one ends but i believe it may be possible to have some way around it.

For now with this code you can easily launch 3 queries at a time, then when they end up 3 more and so on.
For your other request i'll think about it :)

Comment: If you want to try this locally remember the spawner :P

Comment: Awesome!  I had no idea about wait, inheritlib, or waitfor... These are all great.  I haven't been able to get this to work locally though.  I don't have admin rights to the machine, and am not sure if the spawner is running or how to check, or what host= I would put if it were.

Comment: Is there a way for me to declare a macro that will work within all 3 rsubmit statements?

Comment: Hi :)
Ok for the macro i dont have a way to check it now but i believe your best bet is having your macro saved in a .sas file and have your three rsubmit start with an %include to include that file with the macro.
As for testing it locally you can launch the spawner manually, its usually located in the same directory of sas.exe , for example it may be on d:\sas\sas foundation\sas 9.2\spawner.exe
It will launch a cmd window saying "waiting for TCP connection"
as for the host you can use
%LET host1=yourcomputername;
%LET host2=yourcomputername;
or
%LET host1=localhost;
%LET host2=localhost;

Comment: For documentation and tracking purposes it'd be easiest to have it all in one program, so for now I'm putting my giant macro (which is a giant query with 11 tables and 30 fields, which I'm calling 36 times for each month for a 3 year period) into each rsubmit statement.  I tried using a sysrput or a syslput, but I couldn't get those to work for the macro.

Answer (score 2):

On some platforms (Windows and UNIX for sure), if the configuration allows your SAS session to interact with the OS, then the `SYSTASK` statement gives you the ability to executes, lists, or terminates asynchronous tasks. Combined with the `WAITFOR` statement, you can do something like this:

```
systask command "sas prog1.sas" taskname=sas1;
systask command "sas prog2.sas" taskname=sas2;
systask command "sas prog3.sas" taskname=sas3;
waitfor _all_ sas1 sas2 sas3; /* suspend current session until the three jobs are finished */
```

See documentation on [SYSTASK](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/hostwin/63285/HTML/default/viewer.htm#win-stmt-systask.htm) and [WAITFOR](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/hostwin/63285/HTML/default/viewer.htm#win-stmt-waitfor.htm) statements (for the Windows Platform).

Answer (score 0):

SAS Grid Computing? http://support.sas.com/rnd/scalability/grid/index.html

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not trying to use multiple computers.